# how to force Glue DynamicFrame to fail if data doesn't conform to the dataframe schema?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, pyspark

I have a Glue job (running on spark) that simply convert a CSV file to Parquet. I don't have control over the CSV data and as a result I want to capture any inconsistency between the data and the table schema during the conversion to Parquet. For instance if a column is defined as Integer, I want the job gives me an error if there is any string value in that column! Currently, DynamicFrame resolves this by giving choices (string and integer) in the resulted Parquet file! which is helpful for some use cases but I'm wondering if there is any way that enforce the schema and have the glue job to throw error if there is any inconsistency. Here is my code:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(databasem=mdbName, table_namem=mtable, transformation_ctx="datasource0")
df = datasource0.toDF()
df = df.coalesce(parquetFileCount)
df = convertColDataType(df, "timestamp", "timestamp", dbName, table)
applymapping1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df,glueContext,"finalDF")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": path}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using spark native lib instead of using glue lib

Instead of reading from catalog, read from the corresponding s3 path with custom schema and failfast mode

```
schema = StructType ([StructField ('id', IntegerType(), True),
StructField ('name', StringType(), True)]
df = spark.read.option('mode', 'FAILFAST').csv(s3Path, schema=schema)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I figured it out that the Glue catalog can be integrated with spark sql. So I can run something like this: spark.sql("SELECT * FROM example") to read a specific table (example in this case) from Glue catalog into a data frame. But I'm wondering if there is any way to FAILFAST this too?!

Comment: I was able to the get Schema in StructType from the dataframe that being returned by spark.sql("SELECT * FROM example").

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar data type issue that I was able to solve by importing another df that I knew was in the correct format.  Then I looped over the columns of the two dfs and compared their data types. In this example I reformated the data types where necessary:

```
    df1 = inputfile
    df2 = target
    if df1.schema != df2.schema:
        colnames = df2.schema.names
        for colname in colnames:
            df1DataType = get_dtype(df1, colname)
            df2DataType = get_dtype(df2, colname)
            if df1DataType != df2DataType:
                if df1DataType == 'timestamp':
                    not_string = ''
                    df2 = df2.withColumn(colname, df2[colname].cast(TimestampType()))
                elif df1DataType == 'double':
                    not_string = ''
                    df2 = df2.withColumn(colname, df2[colname].cast(DoubleType()))
                elif df1DataType == 'int':
                    not_string = ''
                    df2 = df2.withColumn(colname, df2[colname].cast(IntegerType()))
                else:
                    not_string = 'not '

                print(not_string + 'updating: ' + colname + ' - from ' + df2DataType + ' to ' + df1DataType)

     target = df2
```